# Proper Set Notation

Tags: group-theory

I am currently working on a group theory project, and have come to the topic of conjugacy classes. For a group $\zeta$, the conjugacy class containing the element $A$ is defined to be the set of all elements formed by the operation $XAX^{-1}$ for all $X\in\zeta$. I am tempted to write this as something along the lines of the conjugacy class containing $A$ is

$$\{XAX^{-1}\quad \text{for }X\in\zeta\}$$

which is similar to how one might write this in python. I much prefer this form of notation as opposed to writing

$$X, AXA^{-1}, BXB^{-1}...ZXZ^{-1}$$

which is how I've often seen it written. Note that in this case we have a set: repeat elements are omitted. Is there a formal notation that I can take advantage of?

Comment: You usually write this using set builder notation: either your suggestion or $\{ X A X^{-1} \mid X \in \zeta\} $ or $\{ X A X^{-1} : X \in \zeta\}$ or, if you're lazy, $\{ X A X^{-1}\}$ (I consider this last one bad practice, but it's common so you should know it)

Comment: Be aware it's not very common to use uppercase letters for elements. They are conventionally reserved for sets. This might be different with conjugacy classes in some literature, but as general practice I would avoid it. Also recall the notation $Ha$ and $aH$ for cosets, so you can simplify your notation by considering equivalence classes rather than individual elements

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen The group theory textbook that I have learned from (Tinkham Group theory in quantum mechanics) uses capitals exclusively for group elements. I am following a similar notation as I am developing a learning resource which, to my understanding, will be used in conjunction with his textbook. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thank you for the quick answer, this helps a lot!